# several EARs, JPA and interfaces

Tags: jpa, ejb, marshalling, corba, ear

I have working **app1.ear**, containing:

- JPA entity, *MyObjectImpl*, implementing interface *MyObject* from **api.jar**
- **api.jar** with *MyObject* interface and EJB Remote interface
- **ejb.jar** with EJBs providing methods to access and modify JPA Entities

Second **app2.ear** is supposed to communicate with **app1.ear** using ONLY interfaces in **api.jar**. Everything works fine when passing Java basic types between ears.
But when **app2.ear** tries to retrieve from **app1.ear** instance of *MyObject* - CORBA MARSHAL exception is raised, saying that *MyObjectImpl* class  can not be found:

```
"IOP00810257: (MARSHAL) Could not load class com.zzz.MyObjectImpl"
```

Placing *MyObjectImpl* in **app2.ear** solves the issue, but I don't want to expose JPA implementation to other ear applications. 
Am I missing something or my approach is wrong? Please advise what to do or where to dig.
Many thanks in advance!

PS: Server GF 3.0.1, no GF-specific deployment descriptors, both ears running on the same JVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impl classes are required during deserialization. Another approach would be to use XML or JSON or protobuff, if you doesn't want to expose the impl classes.

Comment: my main concern is to hide JPA annotations. would it be possible that way: MyObjectImpl implements MyObject, MyObjectJPA extends (just annotates) MyObjectImpl, having MyObject and MyObjectImpl available to other ears? Will container deserialize MyObjectJPA into MyObjectImpl? Cant believe there's no way to hide JPA annotation from clients.